# Two question about mdf file in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I don't have any experience in SQL databases. 
I want to use Microsoft SQL server and i need to ask two questions:

1. I want to know what are the disadvantage and advantage of saving the data in the mdf file.
2. Is there some easy way to 'copy' the data that i saved in the mdf file to the regular table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Question doesn't make sense: All data is stored in .mdf or .ndf data files (in reality the extension doesn't matter, it's just a convention)

2) You seem to be mixing the concept of a table and a data file. Backups are used to create safe copies of your data. The tables you see in SSMS are stored in data files (via filegroups).

Comment: maybe i was not clear ... i have in the SQL Server Management Studio the tables - and to see my mdf file i need to 'attach' it in the SQL Server Management Studio. My question was about copy the data from the mdf file that i have to the table that are in the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The table is stored inside the .mdf, so when you attach the .mdf, the table is now available to you. It doesn't make any sense to copy the table out of the .mdf into the database -- the .mdf *is* the database. It's like asking, "I've attached this thumb drive to my computer, now how do I copy this file off the thumb drive to the "thumb drive" device that is in Windows Explorer?" It makes no sense to ask about copying it, because it's *already there.*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know anything about SQL Server, you should start by finding a good book (and go to a good training course) to understand the basic concepts. The documentation is very extensive, but it's really a reference and not a learning tool.

Having said that, have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) on files and filegroups in SQL Server? All data in SQL Server is stored in .mdf (and possibly .ndf) files. Unless you're using SQL Server Compact, I believe.

And what are "regular tables"? Are you perhaps using Access as a front-end to SQL Server?

Comment: in the 'regular tables' i mean the tables that i see when i open the SQL Server Management Studio. i dont using access as front-end.